# php loop problems

Tags: php, mysql

noob problem: i have some issues with a loop in php...here is the code (i used the same methodology for other pages and it works); the code it is supposed to display the names of the products from a order, it works, but it is not showing the very first product , i don't know why :

```
<?php $i=1; while($row_selectOrderItems = mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $i; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_selectOrderItems['pro_name']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_selectOrderItems['pro_price']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_selectOrderItems['q']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row_selectOrderItems['q']*$row_selectOrderItems['pro_price']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
```

and here is the code where i used mysqli_fetch_array before the loop

```
        $query_selectOrderItems = "SELECT *,order_items.quantity AS q  FROM orders,order_items,products WHERE order_items.order_id='$order_id' AND order_items.pro_id=products.pro_id AND order_items.order_id=orders.order_id";
        $result_selectOrderItems = mysqli_query($con,$query_selectOrderItems);                  
        $row_selectOrderItems=mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems);
```

Does anyone have any idea how should i modify this code? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that the first row shown in the result has an `$i` value of `2`?  Do you have any client-side styling which is just hiding the first row?  Check the page source for the exact HTML in the response.

Comment: for showing the very first product you have to use with sql query with `DESC`.

Comment: the first row shown in the result it is starting with 1, like normal, i mean, it is starting with number 1, the it continues okay with 2, and 3 etc., but  number 1 is assigned the product number 2, and so on...just the name of my first product doesn't appear

Comment: usually the first position of an array it's the index 0, try with 0 instead of 1

Comment: $i = 0 is what you need not $i = 1

Comment: i tried and it isn't working....if i write 0 in my code, my products list will start with serial number 0 and that's all, the first product doesn't appear

Comment: @mihaelaa077: If the first row shown has the value of `1` for `$i` then the `while` loop is clearly not "jumping over the first iteration" as described in the question.  Perhaps your query (which we can't see) is returning data (which we can't see) that you don't expect?  Perhaps the problem is in other code (which we can't see)?  It sounds like you've simply made assumptions about the problem and are asking about those assumptions, not about the problem.

Comment: i didn't know how to describe the question :D i tried my best

Comment: the query is returning the data i expect, but it is just not showing the very first product from my order

Comment: @mihaelaa077: How have you confirmed that the data being returned by your query is what you expect?  Or perhaps you're calling `mysqli_fetch_array` once before the start of the loop?

Comment: i used myqli_fetch_array once before the start of the loop at the begining of the code for the page, here is how it is used:

Comment: $query_selectOrderItems = "SELECT *,order_items.quantity AS q  FROM orders,order_items,products WHERE order_items.order_id='$order_id' AND order_items.pro_id=products.pro_id AND order_items.order_id=orders.order_id";
   $result_selectOrderItems = mysqli_query($con,$query_selectOrderItems);     
   $row_selectOrderItems=mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems);

Comment: @mihaelaa077: Please edit the question to include relevant code.

Comment: done, and i'm sorry if it sounds a little bit ambiguous the question, it's my first time posting a question here :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$row_selectOrderItems=mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems);
```

remove this line, so that, it will not read the 1st result at starting.
Now, when you use it in the while loop, it reads the first line

Answer (score 0):

You're reading and ignoring the first record in the results.  Consider how your loop works:

```
while($row_selectOrderItems = mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems))
```

Each iteration calls `mysqli_fetch_array`, stores the record in `$row_selectOrderItems`, then uses that to display the record.  Then consider what you do *before* the loop:

```
$row_selectOrderItems = mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems);
```

You're doing exactly that same thing, but *not* displaying that first record.

Simply remove that first call to `mysqli_fetch_array` before the loop.

Answer (score -1):

may be you used mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems) before this for loop.
check once

Comment: it is used  at the beginning of the code for this page ; here is the code :

Comment: $query_selectOrderItems = "SELECT *,order_items.quantity AS q  FROM orders,order_items,products WHERE order_items.order_id='$order_id' AND order_items.pro_id=products.pro_id AND order_items.order_id=orders.order_id";
   $result_selectOrderItems = mysqli_query($con,$query_selectOrderItems);     
   $row_selectOrderItems=mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectOrderItems);